# IotHub Device Managment in Azure SDK for .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-iot-hub, .net-5, azure-sdk-.net

I need to execute the following command through the Azure SDK for .NET

`az iot hub device-identity update -d DeviceName -n IoTHubNames --sta enabled`

Is there a library that I can install through Nugget to do this?

Comment: Does my answer useful to you? If you need further help ,pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure.IoT.DeviceUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/iot.deviceupdate-readme-pre#install-the-package). But you cannot use the command `az` cmd directly in the SDK code.

I recommend you to use rest api, I think restapi is more convenient for the meaning and usage of each parameter.

[Devices - Create Or Update Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/createorupdateidentity)